# duplicated rows in select query

Tags: sql

I am trying to run a query to get all the `customers` from my database. These are my tables in a diagram :

[image]

when running the query by joining the table Companies_Customers and the Customers table based on the customerId in both tables(doesn't show in the join table in the pic), I get duplicate rows, which is not the desired outcome. 
This is normal from a database standpoint since a Customer can be related to different companies (Companies can share single customer).

My question is how do I get rid of the duplication via SQL.

Comment: you can use the `DISINCT`  keyword to get distinct data. please refer [msdn link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-examples-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#c-using-distinct-with-select)

Comment: your getting duplicates because your table has many customers across many companies as you have said
using distinct will solve your issue.

Comment: distinct on which id ?

Comment: I don't understand the question, to get all customers, run `select * from customers`

Comment: Your model doesn't look right. The Company name belongs in the Company table. Also, what is CompanyCustomerId ? Is this 1 field or a concatenated field ? As others have said, if you just want customers, then just query the customers table. Perhaps you can clarify exactly what you need to get out of the tables.

Answer (score 0):

There can be 2 approaches to your problem.

Either only select data from Customers table:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
```

Or select from both tables joined together, but without CompanyName and with `GROUP BY CompanyCustomerId` - although I highly suggest the first approach.